# Compassionate vampire short story

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recover a vampire related post-apocalyptic short story. The story takes place with the earth frozen in a nuclear winter. Humankind, what's left of them, have been reduced to savages. The protagonist, a vampire, is vainly searching for human prey.  He has the ability to fly and also can sense other vampires and humans at a distance.  He is touched by the plight of an innocent young girl about to be assaulted by a band of brutish men.  The story was found in a collection of SF short stories, but that's about all I can remember about it.

Comment: The novel [Vampire Winter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2357791.Vampire_Winter) by Lois Tilton is about a vampire in Chicago in a nuclear winter. I can't find my copy to check, but I don't recall the scene with the girl though the vampire does befriend humans and protects them.

Comment: Vampire Winter sounds interesting, but the story I'm look for is a short story - definetly not a novel.

Comment: Just as a reminder, you have other questions where you accepted the answer by comment, but did not click on the checkmark to actually accept.